# Something wrong when I import an Eclipse project to Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse

Here is the project structure after import:
[image: project structure after import]

splashActivity is the main project, others are the Library project

When I build the project, the console shows:
[image: Console output]

I don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Change your package name of the Test application so it's not the same. Android Studio generates Test projects but might have messed up the naming and it seems like it can't handle duplicates.